# Google Earth Engine: reduceRegion on multiple bands of daily aggregates

Tags: google-earth-engine, google-earth-engine-javascript-api, zonal-statistics, aggregation, reducers

I found this [**hourly** climate-dataset](https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/datasets/catalog/ECMWF_ERA5_LAND_HOURLY#bands) in the GEE catalog, which I want to utilize, to get the **daily** mean value for six different bands for the time between 2017 and 2022 based on one user-defined AOI (that is roughly the coastal region of New South Wales). So far, I only got a very basic reduceRegion script running for one band and one month.

```js
var geometry = table.geometry();

var aDate = ee.Date.fromYMD(2016,12,31);
var days = ee.List.sequence(1, 31);
var dates = days.map(function(d) {
  return aDate.advance(d, 'day');
});

var dataset = ee.ImageCollection("ECMWF/ERA5_LAND/HOURLY")
  .filterDate('2017-01-01', '2017-02-01')
  .filterBounds(geometry);

var daily_means = dates.map(function(date) {
  var day = ee.Date(date);
  return dataset
    .filterDate(date, day.advance(1, 'day'))
    .select('temperature_2m')
    .mean();
});

var zonal_means = daily_means.map(function(img) {
  var daily_img = ee.Image(img);
  return daily_img.reduceRegion({
    reducer: ee.Reducer.mean(),
    geometry: (table),
    scale: 5000,
    crs: 'EPSG:4283'
  });
});

print(zonal_means);
```

This code for one year will timeout because the user memory is exceeded.

I don't expect total automation because there's a lot of computation that has to be done here, but there has to be a way of doing this thing more efficient. How can I make this code more practicable?

Answer (score 0):

This is very much dependent on the size of the area, which you haven't provided. One simple thing to try is to set `tileScale` to `16` your `reduceRegion()` call. According to the docs:

> **tileScale** (Float, default: 1):
>
> A scaling factor between 0.1 and 16 used to adjust aggregation tile size; setting a larger tileScale (e.g. 2 or 4) uses smaller tiles and may enable computations that run out of memory with the default.

```
var zonal_means = daily_means.map(function(img) {
  var daily_img = ee.Image(img);
  return daily_img.reduceRegion({
    reducer: ee.Reducer.mean(),
    geometry: (table),
    scale: 5000,
    crs: 'EPSG:4283',
    tileScale: 16
  });
});
```